# Como apresentar os 3 últimos índices de um array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

estou recebendo do backend um array com alguns índices, se o array tiver por exemplo (0, 1, 2, 3), devo apresentar (1, 2, 3), se tiver (0, 1, 2), vai apresentar (0, 1, 2), mas preciso apresentar sempre os 3 últimos índices do array que estou recebendo, só estou conseguindo apresentar o ultimo, alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o método slice pode te ajudar!

```
var myarray = [0, 1, 2, 3]
console.log(myarray.slice(-3))
```

Saída:

> [1, 2, 3]